# Can't bind to 'pdfTitle' since it isn't a known property of 'app-pdf-viewer'

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, pdf-viewer

I try to get lazy loading working. But when I remove de module who is responsible for lazy loading in the app.module. The application doesn't work anymore.

Googled a lot. Changed code

So I have a dossier.module.ts, like this:

```
 imports: [
        RouterModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DossierRoutingModule,
        PdfViewerModule,
        SharedModule
        ],

  declarations: [
        DossierComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent,
        DossierEntryComponent,
        DossierEntrySummaryComponent,
        DossierHistoryComponent,
        DossierLabComponent,
        DossierMedicationComponent,
        DossierMiscComponent,
        DossierPhysicalComponent,
        DossierPdfComponent,
        PdfViewerComponent,
        BrochureDetailComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],
```

And I have a DossierRoutingModule:

```
const dossierRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DossierComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'voorgeschiedenis', pathMatch: 'full', CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
      {path: 'voorgeschiedenis', component: DossierHistoryComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
      {path: 'lichamelijk', component: DossierPhysicalComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
      {path: 'lab', component: DossierLabComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
      {path: 'overig', component: DossierMiscComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
      {path: 'medicatie', component: DossierMedicationComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]   },
      {path: 'correspondentie', component: DossierCorrespondenceComponent, CanActivate: [AuthGuard]  },
    ]
  },
];
```

and in the app.module.ts I removed the dossierModule. But I still get this error:

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'pdfTitle' since it isn't a known property of 'app-pdf-viewer'.
1. If 'app-pdf-viewer' is an Angular component and it has 'pdfTitle' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("cklink]="{url: '/informatie', label: 'Terug'}"></app-topbar>
<app-pdf-viewer [hidden]="!pdfLoaded" [ERROR ->][pdfTitle]="brochureName" (back)="handlePdfBack()" >
</app-pdf-viewer>
"): ng:///AppModule/BrochureDetailComponent.html@1:38
'app-pdf-viewer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-pdf-viewer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-pdf-viewer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-topbar [backlink]="{url: '/informatie', label: 'Terug'}"></app-topbar>
[ERROR ->]<app-pdf-viewer [hidden]="!pdfLoaded" [pdfTitle]="brochureName" (back)="handlePdfBack()" >
</app-pdf"): ng:///AppModule/BrochureDetailComponent.html@1:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
    at compiler.js:22639
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
    at compiler.js:22549
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
```

But how is this possible? Because I have   PdfViewerComponent included in de dossier.module.ts.

So how to fix this?

Thank you

and in the app.routes.ts file I have this:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/dossier', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dossier', loadChildren: './dossier/dossier.module#DossierModule' },
```

and the imports of app.module.ts looks now like this:

```
imports: [
    AdviceModule,
    TrainingModule,
    MeasurementModule,
    SettingsAccountModule,
    ObjectiveModule,
    TodoModule,
    PanelModule,
    EcheqModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DragulaModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

oke, this is the hole: dossier.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DossierRoutingModule,
        PdfViewerModule,
        SharedModule
        ],

    declarations: [
        DossierComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent,
        DossierEntryComponent,
        DossierEntrySummaryComponent,
        DossierHistoryComponent,
        DossierLabComponent,
        DossierMedicationComponent,
        DossierMiscComponent,
        DossierPhysicalComponent,
        DossierPdfComponent,
        PdfViewerComponent,
        BrochureDetailComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],

    exports: [
        DossierComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent,
        DossierEntryComponent,
        DossierEntrySummaryComponent,
        DossierHistoryComponent,
        DossierLabComponent,
        DossierMedicationComponent,
        DossierMiscComponent,
        DossierNavigationComponent,
        DossierPhysicalComponent,
        DossierPdfComponent,
        PdfViewerComponent,
        BrochureDetailComponent,
        //PdfViewerControlsComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],
})

export class DossierModule {}
```

my app.routes.ts file looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthCallbackComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/dossier', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dossier', loadChildren: './dossier/dossier.module#DossierModule' },

  {path: 'instellingen', loadChildren: './settings/settings.account.module#SettingsAccountModule'},


  {
    path: 'gezondheid',
    component: HealthComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
    {
      path: 'gezondheid/edit',
      component: AddIndicatorComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
      path: 'gezondheid/Measurement/:meting',
      component: MeasurementComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
   {
     path: 'gezondheid/Lifestyle/:task',
     component: TaskComponent,
     canActivate: [AuthGuard]
   },
  {
    path: 'webshop',
    component: WebshopComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'selfcare',
    component: SelfcareComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'advies/archief',
    component: AdviceArchiveComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'informatie',
    component: AdviceInformationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'informatie/brochure/:brochure',
    component: BrochureDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'advies/:advies',
    component: AdviceComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'advies/detail/:id',
    component: AdviceDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'advies',
    redirectTo: 'advies/huidig',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'chat',
    component: ChatFullComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },

  {
    path: 'hulpbronnen',
    component: ResourcePageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'hulpbronnen/detail/:hulpbronId',
    component: ResourceDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'echeq',
    component: EcheqOverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'echeq/detail/:echeqId',
    component: EcheqProcessComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'help',
    component: HelpPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },

   {
     path: 'instellingen/organisatie/:id',
     component: SettingsOrganisationDetailComponent,
     canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     pathMatch: 'full'
   },
  {
    path: 'trainingen',
    component: TrainingComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'doel/:id',
    component: ObjectiveComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
   {
     path: 'doelen',
     component: ObjectiveListComponent,
     canActivate: [AuthGuard]
   },
  {
    path: 'trainingen/:training',
    component: TrainingDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and for example settingsRoutingModule looks like this:

```
const settingsRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: SettingsNavigationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
     {path: '', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     {path: 'account', component: SettingsAccountComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

     {path: 'apparaten' , component: SelfcareComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     {path: 'apps' , component: SettingsAppsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     {path: 'indicatiepermissies' , component: SettingsIndicatorPermissionsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     {path: 'algemeen' , component: SettingsGeneralComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     { path: 'algemeen', component: SettingsGeneralComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
     {path: 'log' , component: SettingsLogComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
   },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class SettingsRoutingModule {}
```

But if I remove the SettingsAccountModule from the app.module.ts file. The application breaks.

So for example I do this in the app.module.ts then the application  Angular cant find the components anymore.

```
imports: [
    AdviceModule,
    TrainingModule,
    MeasurementModule,
   // SettingsAccountModule,
    ObjectiveModule,
    DossierModule,
    TodoModule,
    PanelModule,
    EcheqModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DragulaModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule,
    ChartsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You need to import your failing component in the module which is throwing the error, also use AOT with your ng serve script

You need to add your reusable components in your module in the exports array:

```
@NgModule({

    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DossierRoutingModule,
        PdfViewerModule,
        SharedModule
        ],

    declarations: [
        DossierComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent,
        DossierEntryComponent,
        DossierEntrySummaryComponent,
        DossierHistoryComponent,
        DossierLabComponent,
        DossierMedicationComponent,
        DossierMiscComponent,
        DossierPhysicalComponent,
        DossierPdfComponent,
        PdfViewerComponent,
        BrochureDetailComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],

    exports: [
        DossierComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceComponent,
        DossierCorrespondenceItemComponent,
        DossierEntryComponent,
        DossierEntrySummaryComponent,
        DossierHistoryComponent,
        DossierLabComponent,
        DossierMedicationComponent,
        DossierMiscComponent,
        DossierNavigationComponent,
        DossierPhysicalComponent,
        DossierPdfComponent,
        PdfViewerComponent,
        BrochureDetailComponent,
        //PdfViewerControlsComponent,
        TopbarComponent
    ],
})

export class DossierModule {}
```

Comment: import your DossierModule into your appModule and try

Comment: But the strange thing is that if I put the dossierModule in the app.module everything works. but if I remove the dossierModule it doesnt work anymore

Comment: Yes, then it works. But then it isnt anymore lazy loding still?

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? in Angular 8 they introduced a new lazy loading syntax

Comment: I am using angular 6

Comment: Try this syntax: loadChildren: () => import('pathToYourModule').then(mod => mod.YourModule)

Comment: #Robert  Where I have to put that? Thank you

Comment: In your app-routing.module, instead of your current loadChildren when you load your lazy loading modules

Comment: So you mean like this: {path: '', redirectTo: '/dossier', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dossier',  loadChildren: () => import('./dossier/dossier.module').then(mod => mod.DossierModule)  },

Comment: And then remove the dossierModule from app.module?

Comment: But if I remove the dossierModule from App.module I still get the error

Comment: And I then get this error: src/app/app.routes.ts(41,42): error TS1323: Dynamic import cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules.

Comment: But oke, I have read that in Angular 6 you still have to get your lazy loading module in your app.module. But is that correct?

Comment: Do you have a project repo?, if you load your module in your appmodule indeed is not lazy loading

Comment: project repo? What do you mean? You have email? Then I can sent you the files . Because it is big project

Comment: A project repository in github / stackblitz, if you upload your project i can give it a look

Comment: Check your email and remove your adress from your comment please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196577/discussion-between-robert-garcia-and-mightycode-newton).